# Android: не находит com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

Tags: android

Android Проект не видит SerializedName, а раньше все работало

[image: не видит SerializedName]

Comment: Попробуйте удалить `.idea\libraries` папку из проекта и заново синзронизировать проект через gradle

Comment: удалил, синхронизировал, все осталось так же

Comment: А зависимость на месте - может случайно удалили? И вы вообще-то в курсе откуда и для чего эта аннотация, в смысле она вам точно нужна в этом классе?

Comment: Ещё может помочь удаление папки `cache` (точно не помню как называется) в месте нахождения gradle. Это примерно тут: `c:/users/AppData/.gradle` или `c:/users/.gradle`

Comment: У меня "мак". По поводу "для чего она там", оно было там сначала, поэтому я озаботился

Comment: Аннотация - для парсинга JSON гугловой либой Gson. Её, кстати, не стоит с Kotlin использовать, т.к. она не может в котлиновские Nullsafty штуки. Ну и в одном классе держать представление для таблицы в БД и для JSON -идея которая ведёт к сложно поддерживаемому коду с костылями и багами.

Comment: @VasiliyK, поищите в маковской папке юзера папку `.gradle/cache`. Она, скорее всего скрытая, так что надо объяснить яблочной ОСи что вы реально хотите видеть файлы, которые от вас решили яблочники скрыть)

Comment: Ну и Invalidate Cache and Restart в студии можно попробовать выполнить. Ещё удалить `.gradle` в корне проекта. И проверить, что студия последней версии. Сейчас это, вроде, 4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло удаление gradle/cache.

Comment: В рамках проекта, или кэшей уровня пользователя?

Comment: точно не скажу уже

Answer (score 0):

Недавно было такое в одном проекте, кажется связано с обновлением студии.

Помогло явное добавление зависимости `gson` в проект.

То есть у большинства при использовании `gson` + `retrofit` зависимость такая:

```
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$gsonVersion"
```

А нужно сделать так:

```
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$gsonVersion"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'
```

Comment: это помогло, спасибо